# javascript won't run inside php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following php page, 
which has a dropdown box and when the value closed is chosen it is meant to open a text box. 
I have embdedded the javascript inside php but for some reason it is not working.

```
<?php


    require_once "/var/www/users/user.php";
    $user = new CHUser(2);



    require_once "/var/www/template/template.php";
    $template = new CHTemplate();


   require_once "/var/www/ENGINEER/DisplayWIPOnLocation.php";
    $BundleProgress= new CHWIPProgress();
    $todays_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');   

        $ID = $_GET['id']; 

        //$ID = $_POST['ID'];

        $ChurchNo = $_POST['ChurchNo'];
        $SerialNo = $_POST['SerialNo'];
        $MachineType= $_POST['MachineType'];
        $Model = $_POST['Model']; 
        $Location= $_POST['Location'];
        $Priority = $_POST['Priority'];
        $Issue = $_POST['Issue'];
        $Status = $_POST['Status'];
        $Call_Opened = $_POST['Call_Opened'];

        //echo "test component $Component";


     $wip = $BundleProgress-> ListTicketById($_GET['id']);


        foreach($wip as $x) {         


        $ChurchNo = $x['ChurchNo'];
        $SerialNo = $x['SerialNo'];
        $MachineType= $x['MachineType'];
        $Model = $x['Model']; 
        $Location= $x['Location'];
        $Priority = $x['Priority'];
        $Issue = $x['Issue'];
        $Status = $x['Status'];
        $Call_Opened = $x['Call_Opened'];
        $Operator = $x['Operator'];
        $Engineer = $x['Engineer'];
        $Notes = $x['Notes']; 





}   





$content .="
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>

function ShowTB(obj,id){
 txt=obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
 if (txt.match('Pending')){
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility='hidden';
 }
 if (txt.match('Closed')){
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility='visible';
 }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>"; 






$content .="

<p><b>You are changing the status of call no: $ID </b></p>
<table> 
                    <tr><td> <b>ChurchNo</b>:$ChurchNo </td>  </tr> 
                    <tr><td> <b>SerialNo</b>:  $SerialNo</td>  </tr>
                    <tr><td> <b>MachineType</b>: $MachineType</td>  </tr>
                    <tr><td> <b>Model</b>: $Model </td>  </tr>
                    <tr><td> <b>Location</b>:$Location </td>  </tr>
                    <tr><td> <b>Priority</b>: $Priority </td>  </tr>
                    <tr><td> <b>Issue</b>: $Issue </td>  </tr>
                    <tr><td> <b>Status</b>:  $Status </td>  </tr>
                    <tr><td> <b>Date Opened</b>:$Call_Opened </td>  </tr>
                    <tr><td> <b>Operator</b>:$Operator </td>  </tr>
                    <tr><td> <b>Logged By</b>:$Engineer  </td>  </tr>
</table>
</br>

</br> 






                        <table>
                        <form method='post' action='UpdateTicket2.php'>
                        <tr><td><b>Assign to: </b></td> <td> <select name='Assignedto'>
                            <option value='David'>David</option>
                            <option value='Ashley'>Ashley</option>
                            <option value='Pete'>Pete</option>
                            <option value='Mark'>Mark</option>
                            <option value='Rory'>Rory</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                            </tr> 


                         "; 

                        $content .=" 

                        <tr><td><b>Status </b></td>
                        <td>                        
                        <select onchange=\"ShowTB(this,'Date');\" >
                        <option >Open</option>
                        <option >Closed</option>
                        <option >Pending</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <input id='Date' style='visibility:hidden;' >   
                        </td> 
                        <tr>    ";                  


             $content .="                
                         <tr><td><b>Notes:</b></td><td><textarea name='Notes' cols='25' rows='5'>
                            $Notes 
                            </textarea></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><b>Current Time: $todays_date</b></td></tr> 
                        <tr><td><input type='hidden' name='ID' id='ID' value='$ID' /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input type='submit' name ='add'/></td></tr>
                    </form>
                </table>
                ";

               $content .="
               </br> 
               <p> Warning.... </p> 
               <form action='delete.php' method='post'>
               <input type='submit' value='Delete Record' />
               <p><input type='hidden' name='ID' id='ID' value='$ID' /></p>
               </form>"; 



        $template->SetTag("content", $content);
        echo $template->Display();

    ?>
```

Comment: What is the HTML output of the PHP? You can probably find the error there.

Comment: post the console output (chrome developer console) if you want help. Agree with Mooseman that rendered HTML would also help. Or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: just had this .Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Comment: Your javascript doesn't look like it contains any server side variables.  Couldn't you put it in a separate .js file

Comment: its simply just checks the value chosen on the dropbown box, so there really should be any server side variables?

Comment: Guys thanks for you help i fixed it. i echoed the javascript part.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes:
comment all until your program begin in

```
/*

*/
$content .="
```

then change:

```
$template->SetTag("content", $content);
echo $template->Display();
```

for:

```
echo $content;
```

finally, **inside** the script tags write:

```
alert('Javascript is working');
```

I made it and got the program running. You problem is in the $template class, not in this code.

Cheers,